# Object Literal Pattern: can't access a data attribute when binding events

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, object-literal

**Background:**

I am trying to dry up my code using the object literal pattern.

**The object:**

Here is my object:

```
(function(){
    var bookingForm = {
        init: function(){
            this.cacheDOM();
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        cacheDOM: function(){
            this.$nextStep = $('.btn-next-step');
        },
        bindEvents: function(){
            this.$nextStep.on('click', this.nextStep.bind(this));
        },
        nextStep: function(value){
            alert($(value).attr('data'));
        },
        prevStep: function(){

        },
    }
    bookingForm.init();
})();
```

And my button which is supposed to trigger the `nextStep` function

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-next-step" data="2">
    Next Step
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
```

So I am trying to access the data attribute of the button, so when I click it I should get an alert of '2'.

I have tried a number of ways... this current code just alerts 'undefined'.

**Question**

How do I pass my data attribute through to the bound function?

Comment: The parameter passed to an event handler is an event object. Your code seems to expect that the `value` parameter will be a DOM element reference, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the help - don't quite understand... I guess I have named things in a confusing way. $nextStep is the class that I have cached and nextStep is the method on the object... is that right?

Comment: Yes sorry I missed that function that initializes the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to an event listener is the event, not the element. To get the element, use `event.target`

```
    nextStep: function(event){
        alert($(event.target).attr('data'));
```

jQuery normally binds `this` to the target element, but you've overridden that with `this.nextStep.bind(this)`, so `this` contains the `bookingForm` object.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in *bindEvents*. You are binding the same object to function, but the function is hoping to receive an element.
I propose the next change

```
(function(){
var bookingForm = {
    init: function(){
        this.cacheDOM();
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    cacheDOM: function(){
        this.$nextStep = $('.btn-next-step');
    },
    bindEvents: function(){
        var that = this;
        this.$nextStep.on('click', function (e) {
            that.nextStep(this)); // here "this" is the element
            // or you can do that.nextStep(e.target);
        });
    },
    nextStep: function(value){
        alert($(value).attr('data'));
    },
    prevStep: function(){

    },
}
bookingForm.init();
})();
```